# Azure DevOps - query which user "Changed state from 'x' to 'y'

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible in Azure DevOps to run a query to match when "user" = 'Bob' "Changed State from" 'x' to 'y'?

We are working in a Kanban so, state was changed form Design to Development by a User. I want to find any items that were changed by said user from Design to Development.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you will need to call rest api to get these work items.

1. Use [WIQL rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get all workitems.

   `POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.1-preview.2`

   `$query='{ "query": "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.WorkItemType] <> \"\" order by [System.WorkItemType], [System.Id]" }'`
2. Use [Updates-List rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get all the update history and filter the items that were changed by said user from Design to Development. See below full example in powershell script:

See [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to get a Personal Access token.

```
$wurl="https://dev.azure.com/org/proj/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.1-preview.2"
$PersonAcessToken=""
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PersonAcessToken)"))

$query='{
  "query": "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.WorkItemType] <> \"\" order by [System.WorkItemType], [System.Id]"
}'

#call WIQL rest api to get all the work item ids.
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $wurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -ContentType "application/json" -Method post -body $query
$ids = $result.workItems.id

#loop throught all work item to check updates
foreach($id in $ids){
  $upurl="https://dev.azure.com/org/proj/_apis/wit/workItems/$id/updates?api-version=6.1-preview.3"
  
  #call Update-list api to get all the historical updates
  $response=  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $upurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get
  
  $updates = $response.value
  
  foreach($update in $updates){
   
   #Check the items that were changed by said user from Design to Development 
   if(($update.fields."System.State".newValue -eq "Development") -and ($update.fields."System.State".oldValue -eq "Design") -and ($update.revisedBy.displayName -eq "Bob")){
      
      # output the required workitem's id.
      echo $update.workItemId
      break
    } 
    
  }
}
```

Above script will get the work items that are changed by Bob from Design to Development. And output the work ids to the console.

Comment: Thank you @Levi Lu-MSFT this does help me see ones that changed but does not give the lens of who changed from Design to Development. Any thoughts there? Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot query these workitem  by using Query. You will need to use rest api to achieve this. See above updated.